# Manually coding then using dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Is it possible to have one person manually coding a page with HTML and CSS and then have someone else (who isn't a programmer) use Dreamweaver now and then to edit things? Basically, someone is looking for me to create the structure of the webpage manually and then, once I'm done, he can continue to make small changes to it. He would also probably make small changes while I'm working on it. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, there is literally nothing preventing someone from editing an HTML document using Dreamweaver...it's entire purpose is to edit these files.  Also, your question is off-topic.  Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sounds dangerous to me. A non-coder editing your files in Dreamweaver can cause unpredictable changes to your code without realizing it, especially when using the "Design" pane. Also, working on the same file simultaneously could cause your work to be accidentally overwritten by someone else. My advice, though much more complex, is to build a simple CMS the non-coder can use to change content without changing the base code. That being said, if you communicate constantly, your workflow is not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having someone code in Dreamweaver and also hand-code can cause many unforeseeable issues. If you have ever created a site in "DW", you will notice that at the times there is *extra* code that is placed on the page. In many circumstances, this is compositely unnecessary code that can damage the structure of a site. This comes more into play when you get into jquery and php.

The safest way would be to make sure various versions of the code are saved so that if "DW" does add unnecessary code that crashes your page, your able to revert to a older copy. Back in the day when I tried using "DW" and good old notepad I came across issues where my site would break because a extra element was added or a wrong meta tag was automatically generated. I say be very careful and if you absolutely have to use "DW" along with manual coding, have the person doing the manual coding check back through the code for extras not needed. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I know Dreamweaver has some built-in features to facilitate collaboration (for example, it will help you create local and remote versions of your sites and manage the file synchronization between them, and it has a file check-in/check-out system to help you avoid overwriting your teammates' changes). Maybe you should both use it.